# Why does this produce math equations indented with grey bar?

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting

By looking at the posts on Mathematics Stack Exchange I have figured out how to produce an inset of math equations, like this:

> $S=\{1,2,3\ldots \text{ n for }n\in \mathbb{N}\}\\
> Y_{i,j}=\{i|i\in \mathbb{N}\land j|j\in \mathbb{N}\}$

The result that you see, a light grey box to the left of inset equations, is begun by putting a > just before the $ and concluding with an extra return at the end.
I have searched the internet the world over and failed to find this feature documented.  Can someone please point me to some documentation? If this is a LaTeX feature, I can't find that either.

Comment: It is documented in the [help pages](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Perhaps the title should ask "How" rather than "Why"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't part of MathJax or LaTeX; it's part of *Markdown*, which is the Stack Exchange way of formatting posts in general (e.g. italicizing the name [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), or making formatted links).

What you stumbled upon is the [blockquote](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes); the linked Help Center article contains almost all other options available to you.